# Automatically install the .NET framework 3.5 SP1 with .Net 2008 application

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, setup-kit

We have an application that needs the 3.5 SP1 framework and when we click on the prerequisite option in the setup kit we made, we only see the framework without the SP1. When we install, it does not indeed  install the correct one.

Is there a way to make this work?

The application was made in WPF if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Visual Studio Install package, or a third party Installation creator?

Comment: I'm creating a new Setup and Deployment project in Visual Studio 2008. I'm not using any other external software. If I really need to, then I guess I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on my Visual Studio installation and the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 prerequisite is available for selection in setup project.

Make sure you have [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) installed.

Also be aware that the installer for .NET Framework SP1 is not included in Visual Studio SP1 and because of this you will not be able to select the option (Download prerequisites from the same location as my application). If you need to have the installer locally take a look at the following blog post:

[How to Include .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 with Your Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/11/18/how-to-include-net-framework-3-5-sp1-with-your-installer.aspx)